# notepad ++ highlight matching div

Tags: notepad++

When I select a div in notepad ++ it would highlight the matching div via the line on the left  (next to the line numbers).

I've just installed Notepad a fresh on a new machine and its no longer doing this and I can't for the life of me find the option in the settings to turn it on.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are talking about this highlighting (the red line):

[image]

The settings for this are in Settings -> Preferences -> Editing -> **Folder Margin Style**

The one shown in my picture is **Box Tree** and as far as I know is the default. When I played around with it, the highlight colour changed from red to white, but restarting Notepad++ fixed it back to red.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is that option I'm talking about. Although mine isn't highlighting in red any more, or any colour. I'm getting a dashed line  in a different position that links the tags, but it doesn't seem to work as well as the old option. (I can't remember if it used to highlight it this way on my old install?). Screen shot here:http://i.imgur.com/0yagt2x.png

Comment: I just reinstalled notepad ++ it and it came back. I presume something must have gone on during install, as I hadn't changed any settings. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Simply install **HTML Tag Plugin** and go to the tag, press **CTRL+T**, highlights matching tag.

Additionally CTRL+SHIFT+T select tags and contents, and there is command also select only contents. But any shortcut is not assigned this command.

Comment: This is cool, I tried it on my notepad++ and I like how it flashes red on the tag if it does not have a closing div. Nice find Thx.

Answer (score 0):

For the big file I was working on, my workaround to find the extra/missing div was to rename a copy of the file to file.java.  Then replace "/div" with } and "div" with {.

And Bob's your uncle.